# Android getAttributeResourceValue always returns 'default value'

Tags: java, android, xml, attributes

i've created a custom view with an attribute, but I'm not able to get the drawable from the attribute I've defined.

The constructor of the View looks like this:

```
public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attset) {
      super(context, attset);
      foregroundDrawableId = attset.getAttributeResourceValue(R.attr.foreground_drawable_overlay, R.drawable.gear);
      setupDrawing();
}
```

And the xml looks like this:

```
<no.flammbaert.flammbaert.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:foreground_drawable_overlay="@drawable/fargespill_bg_bjorn"/>
```

The attrs.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DrawingView">
        <attr name="foreground_drawable_overlay" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

However when i run this, it always returns the default value from the getAttributeResourceValue.

Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing the app on another device? I had the same problem in the eclipse layout view but when I tested it on a real device, it worked just fine.
Another idea might be, to let R be recreated if you changed the type of the attribut, that fixed it for me

And I know, this post is quite old, but for anyone finding it, I hope I could help you